# Please help me improve and undelete this question

Tags: support

Simple request for help getting a potentially very good question from a new user over the line and undeleted:

[**What factors make a campaign go viral? (formerly "Viral campaign?")**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/what-factors-make-a-campaign-go-viral)

The original wording sounded like a request for brainstorming so I commented asking for clarification about the underlying problem - unfortunately, the only other feedback the user got was a downvote and nothing else, and they deleted their question, presumably with a bad first impression of our site.

Their comment made it clear what the question was about, and it sounds like a really interesting question, so I edited it to be SE-friendly and voted to undelete, but I need a few more votes.

Seems to me like a classic case of someone with a good, very interesting question (how to judge how potentially "viral" your work is) not finding it easy to adapt to our site's way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos on the editing and on coming to meta to get more attention to it! 
Just so this doesn't remain as an unanswered question:

**Question has now been reopened.**